# Solving Clipper Circuit containing battery and resistance in series

Tags: diodes, voltage-clipping

I have learned to solve clipper circuit with and with out battery in parallel to the output node. But have no idea what to do if a resistance also connected with it in series.
There is nothing said about it in my book. How can I solve this circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8UbwP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A general procedure for solving this type of problem will be helpful.

Comment: Hint: In a single branch, for a given current (which you can solve for once you make an assumption about the diode's operating condition), what's the voltage across the resistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps**

1. Consider the circuit in three cases as shown below.
2. In each case, replace diodes with their equivalent model: reverse biased diode with open circuit and forward biased diode with a voltage source (drop) of 0.7V (+ve terminal to anode side).
3. Use node or mesh analysis to find the output.

---

**case1:** only D1 conducts. (\$V_i > 5.7 V\$)

[image]

$$V_{R_1} = (V_i - 5.7)\frac{R1}{R1+R}$$
$$V_o = V_{R_1} + 5.7$$

**case2:** only D2 conducts.(\$V_i < -5.7 V\$)

[image]

$$V_{R_2} = (V_i + 5.7)\frac{R2}{R2+R}$$
$$V_o = V_{R_2} - 5.7$$

**case3:** Neither D1 nor D2 conduct. (\$-5.7 < V_i < 5.7 \$)

[image]

$$V_o = V_i$$

**Note:**  The equivalent model of diode considered is piece-wise linear, an ideal diode in series with a voltage source (drop). You can add a resistance in series also to include the forward resistance of diode. I assumed silicon diode. If using any other diode, replace 0.7V with the cut-in voltage of that diode.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to approach this problem is to look at each half cycle of the input.

Consider the positive half cycle.

Only D1 will conduct so we can ignore the D2 branch of the circuit. D1 can only conduct if the input voltage is greater than B1 (5V) + the forward voltage drop across D1 (say 0V for a 'perfect diode', 0.2V for Germanium and 0.7V for Silicon).

**The output voltage will simply follow the input voltage below this level (as there is no load on the output, i.e open circuit)**

Above this 'clipping' level (B1 + Vdiode) some voltage will be dropped across R and some voltage will be dropped across R1. In this case R = R1 so these voltages will be equal.

**Example calculations:**

Suppose we have a 'perfect' diode and the input is +6V.

R + R1 will have 6 - 5V (=1v) across them. You could use Ohm's law to calculate the current through (R + R1) but simple inspection would tell you as the resistors have equal value each one will drop half that voltage, 0.5V. So the output for a +6V input will be +5.5V. [or for Ge = 5.2 + 0.4V = 5.6V and for Si = 5.7 + 0.15V = 5.85V]

Suppose the peak input was + 20V.

The resistors will have 20 - 5 (=15V) across both so each resistor will drop 7.5V making the output voltage 5 + 7.5  (or 20 - 7.5) = 12.5V [ for Ge = 5.2 + 7.4 = 12.6V and for Si = 5.7 + 7.15 = 12.85V)

By symmetry in this circuit the positive and negative half cycles give symmetrical answers but you could analyze non symmetrical circuits by treating each half cycle separately.