# Ideal diodes and applications

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flXzX9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Question: The input signal V(s) is a square wave of \$\pm\$20V (peak) at 1Hz. Sketch the output waveform V(o). Clearly mark the important voltage levels. Show your calculations.

Comment: Reading this [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/113383/27943) may help you.

Comment: Are you sure you must use ideal diodes? That R1 is quite a hint at least a linear piecewise approximation should be used.

Comment: Both diodes burn out and go open circuit due to BAT1-D1 D2 current path pointed out by various people. So output is +/- 20V square wave. You may wish to reverse 1 diode for thi to mke more sense.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

This circuit has to be wrong. You have a 10 volt battery (ideal voltage source) and two forward conducting diodes across the 10 volt. This means theoretical smoke because if the diodes are ideal then infinite current flows. If the diodes are in fact 1N4148 then there is smoke.

V(s) has no chance of inflicting any signal onto the output due to R1.

Comment: It makes any difference if V(s) is the secondary of a transformer?

Comment: @GRTech - the 10V source is being shorted by two diodes - what difference would you think any signal fed via 1k ohm would make? D2 prevents the voltage on the cathode of D1 rising above 0.7V at best

Comment: No.. just to make more complicate this guaranteed smoke production circuit!